# C++ Read and use RSA Private key in OpenSSL

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, openssl, rsa

Assume that there's a program which uses OpenSSL RSA for it's security and I have the private key that it uses to decrypt/encrypt it's data.

This is a quote from whom that wrote how that programs protocol exactly works :

> For the session opening, the client generates a 256-bits AES session key, and a
>   128-bits AES session IV (Initialisation Vector).
>
> The client sends a GSP SESSION INIT message to the server, encrypted with
>   the client's RSA private key (that is, encrypted with the *private* key). 
>   The RSA private key is the same for all Garena Clients, has been ripped 
>   from the windows EXE, and is given at the end of this file :)
>   Because of this, the encryption is worthless: if someone is able to sniff
>   the GSP session, he can get the encrypted GSP SESSION INIT message, decrypt
>   it with the RSA public key (which can be derived from the RSA private key
>   very easily with OpenSSL), and so get the AES session key and IV.
>
> After the GSP SESSION INIT message, all the other GSP messages are encrypted
>   in AES CBC with the session key and IV. The key and IV stay the same during
>   all the session, in both directions (that is, the IV used for the encryption
>   of each subsequent message is really the *starting IV* and not the last 
>   ciphertext block like it should be).

As he mentioned I just need RSA for once (encrypt GSP SESSION INIT) and after that we communicate with AES CBC.

This is the SSL Class that I use : (This is just RSA Stuff)

```
CGarenaEncrypt::CGarenaEncrypt() {
localKeypair = NULL;
remotePubKey = NULL;

#ifdef PSUEDO_CLIENT
    genTestClientKey();
#endif

init();
}

int CGarenaEncrypt::rsaEncrypt(const unsigned char *msg, size_t msgLen, unsigned char **encMsg, unsigned char **ek, size_t *ekl, unsigned char **iv, size_t *ivl) {
size_t encMsgLen = 0;
size_t blockLen = 0;

*ek = (unsigned char*)malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(localKeypair));
*iv = (unsigned char*)malloc(EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);
if(*ek == NULL || *iv == NULL) return FAILURE;
*ivl = EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH;

*encMsg = (unsigned char*)malloc(msgLen + EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH);
if(encMsg == NULL) return FAILURE;

if(!EVP_SealInit(rsaEncryptCtx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), ek, (int*)ekl, *iv, &localKeypair, 1)) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(!EVP_SealUpdate(rsaEncryptCtx, *encMsg + encMsgLen, (int*)&blockLen, (const unsigned char*)msg, (int)msgLen)) {
    return FAILURE;
}
encMsgLen += blockLen;

if(!EVP_SealFinal(rsaEncryptCtx, *encMsg + encMsgLen, (int*)&blockLen)) {
    return FAILURE;
}
encMsgLen += blockLen;

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(rsaEncryptCtx);

return (int)encMsgLen;
}

int CGarenaEncrypt::rsaDecrypt(unsigned char *encMsg, size_t encMsgLen, unsigned char *ek, size_t ekl, unsigned char *iv, size_t ivl, unsigned char **decMsg) {
size_t decLen = 0;
size_t blockLen = 0;
EVP_PKEY *key;

*decMsg = (unsigned char*)malloc(encMsgLen + ivl);
if(decMsg == NULL) return FAILURE;

#ifdef PSUEDO_CLIENT
    key = remotePubKey;
#else
    key = localKeypair;
#endif

if(!EVP_OpenInit(rsaDecryptCtx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), ek, ekl, iv, key)) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(!EVP_OpenUpdate(rsaDecryptCtx, (unsigned char*)*decMsg + decLen, (int*)&blockLen, encMsg, (int)encMsgLen)) {
    return FAILURE;
}
decLen += blockLen;

if(!EVP_OpenFinal(rsaDecryptCtx, (unsigned char*)*decMsg + decLen, (int*)&blockLen)) {
    return FAILURE;
}
decLen += blockLen;

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(rsaDecryptCtx);

return (int)decLen;
}

int CGarenaEncrypt::readPrivateKey(FILE *fd) {
if(!PEM_read_PrivateKey(fd, &localKeypair, NULL, NULL))
    return FAILURE;

return SUCCESS;
}

int CGarenaEncrypt::init() {
// Initalize contexts
rsaEncryptCtx = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX*)malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));
aesEncryptCtx = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX*)malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));

rsaDecryptCtx = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX*)malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));
aesDecryptCtx = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX*)malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));

// Always a good idea to check if malloc failed
if(rsaEncryptCtx == NULL || aesEncryptCtx == NULL || rsaDecryptCtx == NULL || aesDecryptCtx == NULL) {
    return FAILURE;
}

// Init these here to make valgrind happy
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(rsaEncryptCtx);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(aesEncryptCtx);

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(rsaDecryptCtx);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(aesDecryptCtx);

// Init RSA
EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);

if(EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx) <= 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(ctx, RSA_KEYLEN) <= 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

if(EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &localKeypair) <= 0) {
    return FAILURE;
}

EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(ctx);

// Init AES
aesKey = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/8);
aesIV = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/16);

unsigned char *aesPass = (unsigned char*)malloc(AES_KEYLEN/8);
unsigned char *aesSalt = (unsigned char*)malloc(8);

if(aesKey == NULL || aesIV == NULL || aesPass == NULL || aesSalt == NULL) {
    return FAILURE;
}

// For the AES key we have the option of using a PBKDF (password-baswed key derivation formula)
// or just using straight random data for the key and IV. Depending on your use case, you will
// want to pick one or another.
#ifdef USE_PBKDF
    // Get some random data to use as the AES pass and salt
    if(RAND_bytes(aesPass, AES_KEYLEN/8) == 0) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    if(RAND_bytes(aesSalt, 8) == 0) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    if(EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha256(), aesSalt, aesPass, AES_KEYLEN/8, AES_ROUNDS, aesKey, aesIV) == 0) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
#else
    if(RAND_bytes(aesKey, AES_KEYLEN/8) == 0) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    if(RAND_bytes(aesIV, AES_KEYLEN/16) == 0) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
#endif

free(aesPass);
free(aesSalt);

return SUCCESS;
}
```

And this is how I tried to do all the things :

```
if (!AfxSocketInit())
Util_Log(0, 2, _T("AfxSocketInit() failed."));

FILE* privKey;

int err  = fopen_s( &privKey, "E:\\gkey.pem", "r" );

if( err != 0 ){
    Util_Log(0, 2, _T("Failed to open 'gkey.pem' file."));
    return;
}

err = m_encrypt.readPrivateKey(privKey);

fclose(privKey);

if( err != 0 ){
    Util_Log(0, 2, _T("readPrivateKey Failed."));
    return;
}


sendGSPSessionInit();

bool CGarenaInterface::sendGSPSessionInit(void)
{
FILE *f;
if(AllocConsole()) {
freopen_s(&f, "CONOUT$", "wt", stdout);
SetConsoleTitle(_T("Debug Console"));
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_RED);
}

Util_Log(0, 0, _T("Sending GSP session init ..."));

int nEncSize = 0;
int nDecSize = 0;
uint8_t* EncOut = NULL;
uint8_t* DecOut = NULL;
unsigned char *ek;
unsigned char *iv;
size_t ekl;
size_t ivl;

CByteBuffer *bytebuffer = new CByteBuffer();
CByteBuffer *bytebuffer2 = new CByteBuffer();
bytebuffer->Allocate(50);
bytebuffer->PutBytes(m_encrypt.aesKey, 32);
bytebuffer->PutBytes(m_encrypt.aesIV, 16);
bytebuffer->PutShort(0xF00F);

printf("\n original:\n");
Util_HexPrint(*bytebuffer, bytebuffer->ByteBuffer->len);

nEncSize = m_encrypt.rsaEncrypt(*bytebuffer, bytebuffer->ByteBuffer->len, &EncOut, &ek, &ekl, &iv, &ivl);

printf("encrypted:\n");
Util_HexPrint(EncOut, nEncSize);

nDecSize = m_encrypt.rsaDecrypt(EncOut, nEncSize, ek, ekl, iv, ivl, &DecOut);

printf("decrypted:\n");
Util_HexPrint(DecOut, nDecSize);

bytebuffer2->Allocate(nEncSize + 6);
bytebuffer2->PutInt(258);
bytebuffer2->PutShort(0x00AD);
bytebuffer2->PutBytes(EncOut, nEncSize);

printf("\n final:\n");
Util_HexPrint(*bytebuffer2, bytebuffer2->ByteBuffer->len);

//  m_socket.Create();
//  m_socket.m_buffer = *bytebuffer2;
//  m_socket.nBufLen = bytebuffer2->ByteBuffer->len;
//  m_socket.Connect(GARENA_MAIN_SERVER_ADDRESS, 7456);


delete bytebuffer;
bytebuffer = NULL;
//  delete bytebuffer2;
//  bytebuffer2 = NULL;

free(EncOut);
free(DecOut);
free(ek);
free(iv);
EncOut = NULL;
DecOut = NULL;
ek = NULL;
iv = NULL;


return true;
}
```

[image: proof]

As the picture shows everything works correctly BUT the problem is the server that I connect to, expects a packet with ~200-250 length WHILE mine is ~70. That means when they encrypt their data (which is same between what I use and what original client uses) the encrypted length will be a large number (~240). Also there is an alternative for the original client (What I am actually do) which is written in java generates the correct encrypted data with correct length.

[GCB](https://github.com/uakfdotb/gcb/blob/master/src/gcb/GarenaEncrypt.java)

I think there should be a problem while reading the private key because when I call 
    `PEM_write_PrivateKey(stdout, localKeypair, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL)`
The key that prints in console in completely different from the private key that I want to read OR I'm using wrong key length ?! I don't know.

Any help would be most welcome

Comment: What, exactly, is the question? See [`pem(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html) for reading writing keys. See [`evp(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/evp.html) for encryption and decryption.

Comment: @noloader Sorry but you didn't even tried to read all that I wrote

Comment: actually, I did read through it. `pem(3)` and `evp(3)` answers the question asked in the title (how to read a key and use it). As for your protocol problems - who knows. We can't do anything with the comment from the source file. It does not tell us anything useful. You should check the reference implementation.

Answer (score 0):

first, you have wrong information. EVP_Seal... operation does not use rsa private encryption. EVP_Seal.. use rsa_public_encryption and EVP_Open.. use rsa_private_decryption.

seconds, size of encrypted key depends on RSA key size. in your code you use RSA_KEYLEN as key size. i think your server's key size maybe 2048(bits) long. you use 512(bits) long.